# For mapping, what should i do after connecting to the laser?

Tags: navigation, mapping, sicklms, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

It's my first question and i'm so new to ROS (and even Linux :/ )
Anyway i tried to create a map with laser scanner, Sick LMS100. I installed lms1xx drivers, and i wrote the code  "rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node" then it said It connected to laser...So connection is ok but I dont know what to do next? What are my options for creating a simple map or something like floor plan?

By the way, right now i dont have a robot, just the laser scanner.

Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233622/for-mapping,-what-should-i-do-after-connecting-to-the-laser?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-05-04**:
You should probably start with a simpler topic. Mapping is a rather advanced task in robotics and not the first thing you should try if you have never ROS or Linux. Have you already done the tutorials?

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-04**:
I'm doing the tutorials as well, but i have to do something like basic mapping, floor plan etc as soon as possible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

go for hector_slam if you want to create a floor plan of the environment. First you need to make sure that your laser data is publishing on a /scan topic and then run hector_mapping node available in hector_slam package

http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam

if you browse through hector_slam_launch/launch files you will find tutorial launch file. this is the file you need to launch. next you have to edit your mapping_default.launch and tutorial.launch.

In tutorial.launch file, add these lines at the end

and also set use_sim_time to 'false'

In mapping_default file, use following configuration

"map_frame" value="map" />

"base_frame" value="base_link" />

"odom_frame" value="base_link" />

hope this solves your query

---

Originally posted by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) with karma: 53 on 2016-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-11**:
I connected with laser and checked by rostopic echo /scan and its ok. in another terminal i wrote roslaunch hector_mapping mapping_default.launch. Am i doing right? It says in INFO: lookupTransform base_footprint to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-05-11**:
Don't use a static transform from map to base_link, the node provides that. If you do that it will only map based on the first scan. The map only updates after a certain amount of translation or rotation occurs. If you have a static transform the node will never know when the sensor's moved.

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-18**:
@hashim I tried(finally i managed to create overlay_ws and can able to modify hector_slam) when i modified like you wrote and run hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch It didnt gave error. Thank you soooo much.

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-05-18**:
welcome... kindly mark it as an answer :)

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-18**:
@hashim by the way the map in the rviz is a bit strange. when i move or turn laser around it become a mess. It is like that. http://tinypic.com/r/117zmsn/9

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-05-18**:
Do not yaw too much for getting the accurate map. Basically it depends on the frequency and range of the laser scanner you are using. Hector_slam is build for scanners of 25-30hz. Otherwise keep you scanner level with ground and avoid abrupt movements and yawing

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-05-18**:
Something is wrong. I've used hector_mapping with an LMS100 and had no problem with yaw. How fast are you rotating?

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-18**:
I have LMS100 too. Frequency was 50 hz so i changed it to 25 Hz(in its own program SOPAS) but now when i try to connect it gives error like "Unable to get laser output range"

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-05-18**:
no keep it to 50hz. then... its more than enough

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-05-18**:
share you tutorial.launch and mapping_default.launch files

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-18**:
I cut the power of laser scanner and gave it again :) and now it connected with 25 Hz. i rotate and move it more slowly an results is like http://tinypic.com/r/2dipwmb/9 It looks better than the first

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-05-18**:
better results